# Is there any way to detect texts in an imageView and hide only those texts inside an imageView?

Tags: android, imageview, watermark

I am trying to build an app in which i want to recognize the texts  in an imageView and hide those texts.I'm able to get the text from the image but not able to hide them, is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - how is it you get "text" from an imageview currently?

Comment: using text recognizer..check this-https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextRecognizer